# FaceTime- How do I hide that I have my own iCloud ID from my parents when they call?

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, facetime

I don't want my parents knowing I have my own iCloud ID, because they want to know who I'm calling, even though they can check the bill...or no? Idk, I just want them to be able to FaceTime me without seeing my ID. Is there someway that I could use their iCloud ID when they call me and I call them, then go back and FaceTime my friends with mine? (I'm using an iPhone of coarse) If anyone has a suggestion or any advice, it would help greatly and I would be very grateful. Thank you

Comment: Could you break down why your parents would know your Apple ID? If they communicate with you over FaceTime/iMessages you can set up your phone to send from the phone number always and not accidentally let them know your account name. Also, even if they know your account name, that doesn't let them track anything, no?

Comment: My parents don't want me to have my own ICloud account because they want to be able to see and control everything. And thank you for your help, it's much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open up the Settings app, you can choose what the "caller ID" looks like for both iMessage and FaceTime.

Choose to start new conversations from your mobile number if you don't want to accidentally message them from your email.

It's likely you aren't even divulging the AppleID unless you initiate a new message to them, and again - knowing that doesn't really loop them in to your private matters unless you also give them your password/passcode to the phone itself.